# deploy angular 4 to production host server

Tags: angular, production-environment

i want to deploy my angular 4 project to production server, i follow this instruction from angular.io documentation

> 1. Copy everything (or almost everything) from the local project folder to a folder on the server.
> 2. If you're serving the app out of a subfolder, edit a version of index.html to set the  appropriately. For example, if the URL to index.html is www.mysite.com/my/app/, set the base href to . Otherwise, leave it alone. More on this below.
> 3. Configure the server to redirect requests for missing files to index.html. More on this below.
> 4. Enable production mode as described below (optional).

i already do all of them (except point 3, i use routing to handle this), and also i already run ng build -prod but i have 2 problem now :

1. i only able to access my application from domain/src path and when i use only domain, it will show me folder index
2. i cannot access all of my resource (js / css) that i include in my index.html (without using angular cli)  is marked as 404 not found

UPDATE: below is my index.html file

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Example</title>
      <link href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"                 rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="../src/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="../src/css/sidebar-nav.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="../src/css/spinners.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="../src/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="../src/css/colors/blue.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/select2/css/select2.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/bootstrap-table/bootstrap-table.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css">
      <base href="/example">

      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- Preloader -->
    <div class="preloader">
      <div class="cssload-speeding-wheel"></div>
    </div>
      <app-root>
      </app-root>

    <script src = "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src = "./assets/select2/js/select2.js"></script>
    <script src = "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src = "../src/js/sidebar-nav.js"></script>
    <script src = "../src/js/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>
    <script src = "../src/js/waves.js"></script>
    <script src = "../src/js/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/bootstrap-table/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

is there any way to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using angular-cli?

Comment: @Supamiu : yes, i use it for my development environment, because i follow angular.io tutorial

Comment: Can you please add your index.html file? The one before you build the application.

Comment: What server you deploying with

Comment: @Supamiu : sorry for my late response, i have updated my question with index.html file

Comment: @MikeTung : i use CentOs